# Script to display date for coming bi-monthly Friday

Tags: javascript

Cut Off Date: the cut off date is set as the coming bimonthly Friday (eg cut off dates are Jun 14 and Jun 28. If the submission is done today(June26th), then cut off date is Jun 28. If the submission is done on Jun 29th, the cut off date would be Jul 12. Once it's July 13th the next cutoffdate would be July 26th. And so on, depending on when the user submits the form it will display the correct cutoffdate. I've looked around at a few other examples, but can't find one for what I want.

```
var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime())
document.getElementById('lastsubmission').value =
  (currentDate.getDate()) + '/' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
  currentDate.getFullYear() + '@' + currentDate.getHours() + ':' +
  currentDate.getMinutes() + ':' + currentDate.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Your cutoff date is not clearly defined. Are they second and fourth Fridays of the month? If so, then you want an algorithm to find those days. Not difficult, but what have you tried? The code you've posted just formats a date, it doesn't try to find the 2nd and 4th Fridays.

Comment: Are you open to using a library - I would use moment.js for this because it will handle a lot of the work for you. Also, can you clarify which Fridays are the bimonthly Fridays when there are 5 Fridays in a month?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to get the next Friday after a date that is either the second or fourth Fridays of a month. Something like:

1. Get the second Friday of the date's month
2. If it's before that, return the second Friday
3. If it's after then, get the fourth Friday of the month
4. If it's before then, return the fourth Friday
5. If it's after then, return the second Friday of next month

So you might need a function to get a particular Friday given a date, and some other code to do the rest of the logic, e.g.

```js
// Given a Date, return the nth Friday of that month
function getNthFriday(date, n) {
  // Get first Friday
  let d = new Date(date);
  d.setDate(1);
  let day = d.getDay();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5 - (day > 5? -1 : day));
  // Set to nth Friday
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (n-1)*7);
  return d;
}

// Return the next Friday after date that is either the
// second or fourth Friday's of a month.
function getCutoffDate(date) {
  // Get 2nd Friday
  var friday = getNthFriday(date, 2);
  // If before, return 2nd Friday
  if (date < friday) {
    return friday;
  }
  // Get 4th Friday
  friday = getNthFriday(date, 4);
 
  // If before, return 4th Friday
  if (date < friday) {
    return friday;
  }
  // Otherwise, return 2nd Friday of next month  
  friday = getNthFriday(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 1), 2);
  return friday;
}

// Some tests
[
 new Date(2019,4,30), // 30 May 2019 -> 14 Jun
 new Date(2019,5, 1), //  2 Jun 2019 -> 14 Jun
 new Date(2019,5,13), // 13 Jun 2019 -> 28 Jun
 new Date(2019,5,23), // 23 Jun 2019 -> 14 Jun
 new Date(2019,5,30)  // 30 Jun 2019 -> 12 Jul
].forEach(d => {
  console.log(getCutoffDate(d).toString());
});
```

A library might help with getting the nth Friday, and getting the first day of the next month.